# Apache Spark Web UI on kubernetes not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, helm, apache-spark

hi im having a problem

i'am deploying Apache spark helm chart on kubernetes

bitnami chart : helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

normally the apache spark webui is on port 8080

when i access the webUI here is what i get :

[image]

**what i'am trying to get is UI that i can manage Spark with
something like this :**

to manage Spark :
[image]

i don't if it's a config thing or the ui needs to be added
im not familiar with spark

hope someone ca guide me to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding.

- The first screenshot is Spark Master.
- The second screenshot is for specific Spark application / job. This
  UI will be gone after the application / job terminated. To access
  this Spark UI of terminated applications, needs the Spark History
  Server.

I expect during running, you should be able to navigate from first screenshot page to second screenshot page, which currently cannot. I have an open ticket for this issue at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/16227